# move discussion board library items?

Tags: web-part, library, discussion-board

I have a site where I have a Discussion Board which has Contribute permissions for a group. I want to add a webpart with the ability to read-only (not upload) files. I created 2 groups... one Contribute, one Read, and two librarys (Read_only_Documents and Documents).

Will they see the Upload buttons on the webpart when it is based on a Read-Only Library?

I now notice, when I Insert a document (image) into a Discussion, they see (not as default) both Documents and Read_Only_Documents. This is confusing. I don't want them uploading to this area.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint displays buttons for the current user, so if the user has permission to write to the Read_only_documents library, they will se the Add/Upload button.

Make sure you create groups that reflect the business need. Then use the group to give permissions to your resources.

In this case, you need to make sure that no group have contribute permissions on the Read_only_documents library.